# How to create in indent of a rectangle in Inkscape?

Tags: indentation, inkscape

I've been trying to design something for laser cutting and couldn't figure out how to create an indent of a rectangle. Any ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what you mean. Is it something like this?

[image]

If it is, here is how to do (or any other indent):

Draw your rectangle with the `Create Rectangles and Squares` tool. Transform it to a path (`Path > Object to Path`). You will loose the special properties of the Rectangle tool (F4) (you won't have the `vertical rounding` button any more) but now you'll be able to edit the object with the `Edit paths by nodes` tool (F2). Select this tool and your rectangle. You will see four nodes. To create a dent like in the picture you need more nodes:

Click the upper connecting line of the rectangle (step 1 in image below) and click the `Insert new nodes into selected segments` button (step 2) (be aware that you will only see this button when you select the `Edit paths by nodes` tool)

[image]

After, simply drag one node "inside" the rectangle (step 1 in image below). To get a round shape experiment for example with the `Make selected nodes symmetric` or the other buttons. You will notice little handles attached to the node, drag them around.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, something similar but a rectangle-shaped indent is what I need. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Actually, that's the one, thanks you! I've still yet to figure out how to do a nice indent but you gave me the basics. Fantastic!

Answer (score 5):

Another way: create a second object (int this case another rectangle), place it over the object you want to indent, select all and then Path->Difference (or Ctrl-+).

[image: indent: path difference (Ctrl+-)]

Comment: Indeed, this way involves less steps and lets you create the most complex shapes beforehand.